# Найти все ссылки и вывести все в консоль по строкам

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Найти все ссылки (например href="(.*?)") в исходном коде страницы (например у ya.ru) через регулярные выражения и вывести все в консоль по строкам.

P.S.1

- нужно содержимое href="(.*?)" между двойными кавычками "копировать";
- "в консоль по строкам" - это каждое "копируемое" должно начинаться с
  каждой новой строки и не в линюю или 1 строку;
- скачивать что то не нужно, т.к. в примере ya.ru имеет нужное содержимое для
  "копирования";

Comment: А зачем тут регулярки, если есть ДОМ?

Comment: @Ainar-G вероятно, речь про то, что страницу нужно сначала скачать.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, Здесь непонятно... Он пишет что хочет вывести в консоль, про парсинг ни слова...

Comment: Обязательно регуляркой?

Comment: да, нужны регулярки

Comment: @dvv, А чем вас не устраивает DOM метод? Можете конкретизировать вопрос?

Comment: @Vadim Pedchenko, если без DOM никак, тогда ок. Просто я не могу это совместить. DOM я знаю плохо.

Comment: @dvv, При чем здесь никак? Я же дал вам ответ... И не только я... Что вас не устраивает?

Comment: @dvv, Просто для того чтобы дать вам нормальный ответ, нужно до конца понимать ваши цели... Чего вы хотите добиться???

Comment: dvv, И зачем что то совмещать??? Я дал вам два конкретных решения... Пересмотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так:

> Выводит массив ссылок
>
> ```
> var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
> var links = [];
>
> for(var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
>     var href = a[i].href;
>
>     if(href.length) {
>         links.push(href);
>     }
> }
>
> console.log(links);
> ```
>
> Выводит ссылки построчно:
>
> ```
> var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
>
> for(var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
>     var href = a[i].href;
>
>     if(href.length) {
>         console.log(href);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Я бы добавил проверку `href`, ибо могут быть теги `<a>` без `href`.

Comment: @Ainar-G, Согласен, но это просто пример... Можно сделать через foreach, map, с проверками и т.д... Но мне кажется там цель тривиальная... Могу отредактировать, и добавить проверку, если принципиально))) Или можете сами поправить)

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю такой вариант решения:

```js
var links = document.documentElement.innerHTML.match(/href="(.+?)".*?/gm);
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        console.log(links[i].slice(6,-1));
    }
```

Регулярное выражение если нужно найти только `htpp(s)://` ссылки:

`href="(https?:\/\/.+?)".*?`